# basic facebook graph returning error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok this is not exactly programming or coding question but I need to sort this first before getting into code.

So in order to fetch feed I need to get the page_id but when visiting 
http://graph.facebook.com/dantruat

for this page https://www.facebook.com/dantruat it returns error

but for other pages such as http://graph.facebook.com/notebookspec/ (  https://www.facebook.com/notebookspec  ) it works well.

**So does that mean the page owner can disable the graph or feed for his page? 

What should I do inorder to get feed from those disable ( if owner can ) pages.**

Answer (score 0):

The error could be because the page name is in Thai instead of English. You should report the error to Facebook and see if they can help you out.

Comment: Thai isn't the reason I guess as it work in this case https://www.facebook.com/veerasaak

Comment: In that case, it could be temporary error with the page itself, and you should contact Facebook and report it as a bug in any case.

Comment: Sure i'll report it if you are pretty sure that its a bug, not any kind of page permission limitation by the page owner :)

Comment: The only page permission I can think of that would stop the data from loading could be Age: 18+ or restricted location.